# More specific overload not called

Tags: c++

Given the following two functions, I would expect the first overload to be called if I pass it an `std::pair<const char*, std::size_t>`, since it is more specific than a generic `T`.

```
void foo(const std::pair<const char*, std::size_t>& p)
{
    std::cout << "pair" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void foo(const T& v)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* s = "abc";
    foo(std::make_pair(s, std::size_t(3)));
}
```

However, this program outputs:

```
generic
```

Why is the second overload called, instead of the overload that explicitly takes a `pair`?

Is this a compiler issue?  I happen to be using a pretty old compiler (GCC 4.1.2) at the moment.

Hmm... it probably IS a compiler issue:

http://ideone.com/97XwwZ

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/vV55Ea  Works on VS2010 also.

Comment: Cannot reproduce using g++ (GCC) 4.7.2

Comment: Works as you expect in VS2012, for what it's worth.

Comment: The compiler is never wrong. Until it is...

Comment: Well, old compilers are often wrong.

Comment: Works as you'd expect in VS2010

Comment: [over.match.best]/1 "Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function
`F2` if for all arguments i, ICSi(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(`F2`), and then [...] `F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization" => your compiler is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your compiler is certainly in error. What error it is, will only be speculation, but you are correct that this code should give the more specific output. The sample isn't big or complex enough for any of the more subtle rules to be the cause.

Answer (score 4):

It seems it's just a compiler issue.  I was using an old compiler (GCC 4.1.2).  Using a less ancient compiler seems to result in the correct overload being called

http://ideone.com/97XwwZ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void foo(const std::pair<const char*, std::size_t>& p)
{
    std::cout << "pair" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void foo(const T& v)
{
    std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* s = "abc";
    foo(std::make_pair(s, std::size_t(3)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to overloading resolution, it should prefer the specific one in your example.

I would say that this is a compiler bug due to older version. When compiled using GCC 4.8.1. It outputs

```
pair
```

according to this link: [overloading resolution demo](http://ideone.com/VyJC64)